# Dynamically cast to a proper subclass from parent class in a method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a Java `interface` `PlatformConfigurable`. I also have two classes `PlatformProducerConfig` and `PlatformConsumerConfig`.

Later on, I need to add a common config to both that sets a property to an empty string:

```
    private PlatformConfigurable disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformConfigurable platformConfig) {
        if (platformConfig instanceof PlatformProducerConfig) {
            PlatformProducerConfig oldConfig = (PlatformProducerConfig) platformConfig;
            Map<String, String> additionalConfig = oldConfig.additionalProperties();
            Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
            newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
            return oldConfig.toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
        }
        else if (platformConfig instanceof PlatformConsumerConfig) {
            PlatformConsumerConfig oldConfig = (PlatformConsumerConfig) platformConfig;
            Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
            Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
            newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
            return oldConfig.toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
        }
        return platformConfig;
    }
```

I am casting to producer or consumer config because the `PlatformConfigurable` interface doesn't have `.toBuilder()` or `.build()` methods declared in it, and I don't have access to modify the interface, as I can only implement it.

I would want to get rid of the duplicate code:

```
Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
            Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
            newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
            return oldConfig.toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
```

I was thinking of using lambdas, but I am not 100% sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking [Alex Rudenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62090170/3) a bit further, using generics:

```
private <P extends PlatformConfigurable> P disableHostNameVerificationConfig(P platformConfig, BiFunction<P, Map<String, String>, P> appender) {
    Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
    Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
    newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");

    return appender.apply(platformConfig, newConfig);
}
```

This assumes that it is safe to do this for any subtype of `PlatformConfigurable` (and `PlatformConfigurable` itself).

Then invoke like:

```
disableHostNameVerificationConfig(
    platformProducerConfig,
    (p, config) -> p.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(config).build());

disableHostNameVerificationConfig(
    platformConsumerConfig,
    (p, config) -> p.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(config).build());
```

If you like, create helper methods to hide the `BiFunction`s:

```
private PlatformProducerConfig disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformProducerConfig config) {
  return disableHostNameVerificationConfig(
      platformConfigurable,
      (p, config) -> p.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(config).build());
}

private PlatformConsumerConfig disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformConsumerConfig config) {
  return disableHostNameVerificationConfig(
      platformConfigurable,
      (p, config) -> p.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(config).build());
}
```

---

Actually, I think a better way to do it would be without generics or lambdas: write a method which creates an updated map:

```
private static Map<String, String> newConfig(PlatformConfigurable platformConfig) {
  Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
  Map<String, String> newConfig = additionalConfig != null ? new HashMap<>(additionalConfig) : new HashMap<>();

  newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
  return newConfig;
}
```

and then just have two overloads:

```
private PlatformProducerConfig disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformProducerConfig config) {
  return config.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(newConfig(config)).build();
} 

private PlatformConsumerConfig disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformConsumerConfig config) {
  return config.toBuilder().setAdditionalConfig(newConfig(config)).build();
}
```

Comment: This results in: Cannot resolve method 'toBuilder' in 'P'

Comment: @QuirkyBit it would help if you showed the (relevant) declarations of the classes in your question. It's not apparent that the `toBuilder` method isn't present on `PlatformConfigurable`.

Comment: It's in the question descprition:
I am casting to producer or consumer config because `PlatfromConfigurable` interface doesn't have `.toBuilder()` or `.build()` methods, and I don't have access to modify the interface, as I can only implement it.

Comment: Yep, that did it ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You could just refactor existing code like this:

```
private PlatfromConfigurable disableHostNameVerificationConfig(Platfromonfigurable platfromConfig) {
    if (!(platformConfig instanceof PlatformProducerConfig) && !(platformConfig instanceof PlatformConsumerConfig)) {
        return platformConfig;
    }

    Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
    Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
    newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");

    if (platformConfig instanceof PlatformProducerConfig) {
        return ((PlatformProducerConfig)platformConfig).toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
    }
    return ((PlatformConsumerConfig)platformConfig).toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
}
```

**Update**

Another approach could be to extract functionality related to the builder to separate interfaces and use them in this way:

```
// 1. extend existing `PlatformConfigurable`
public interface BuilderedPlatformConfigurable extends PlatformConfigurable {
    ConfigPlatformBuilder toBuilder();
}

// 2. provide builder interface with common implementation
public interface ConfigPlatformBuilder {
    Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

    BuilderedPlatformConfigurable build();

    default ConfigPlatformBuilder additionalProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.additionalProperties.clear();
        this.additionalProperties.putAll(properties);
        return this;
    }
}

// 3. update PlatformConsumerConfig class (similarly, PlatformProducerConfig)
public class PlatformConsumerConfig implements BuilderedPlatformConfigurable {
    private Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> additionalProperties() {
        return additionalProperties;
    }

    public ConfigPlatformBuilder toBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public static class Builder implements ConfigPlatformBuilder {
        public PlatformConsumerConfig build() {
            PlatformConsumerConfig config = new PlatformConsumerConfig();
            config.additionalPropertie.putAll(this.additionalProperties);
            return config;
        }
    }
}

// 4. provide overloaded method
private PlatformConfigurable disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformConfigurable platformConfig) {
    return platformConfig;
}

private PlatformConfigurable disableHostNameVerificationConfig(BuilderedPlatformConfigurable platformConfig) {
    Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
    Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(Map::of));
    newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");

    return platformConfig.toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
}
```

Comment: What if additional PlatfromXCofing classes are added later? What if their number becomes rather large? Is there a way to make the method more generic?

Comment: This is a good refactoring, but @Andy Turner gave a more general answer. Thank you!

Comment: I provided updated version separating `Buildered` implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding one thing in Alex Rudenko's answer, and making different function to add different implementations of interfaces.

```java
private PlatformConfigurable disableHostNameVerificationConfig(PlatformConfigurable platformConfig) {
    if ((platformConfig == null)) {
        return platformConfig;
    }

    Map<String, String> additionalConfig = platformConfig.additionalProperties();
    Map<String, String> newConfig = new HashMap<>(Optional.ofNullable(additionalConfig).orElseGet(ImmutableMap::of));
    newConfig.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG, "");
    return PlatformConfigurableObject(platformConfig, newConfig);
}
```

So you can handle all instances in a different method, and whenever PlatfromXCofing classes are added later you only have to change this method. Single Responsibility Principle.

```java
private PlatformConfigurable PlatformConfigurableObject(PlatformConfigurable platformConfig, Map<String, String> newConfig){
    if (platformConfig instanceof PlatformProducerConfig) {
        return ((PlatformProducerConfig)platformConfig).toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
    } else if (platformConfig instanceof PlatformConsumerConfig){
        return ((PlatformConsumerConfig)platformConfig).toBuilder().additionalProperties(newConfig).build();
    } else{
    return platformConfig;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good refactoring, but @Andy Turner gave a more general answer. Thank you!